# How to get only second array values on foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

This is how I create and pass the array form a php function.

```
 Query....
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
          array_push($carRate,array($row['rental_type_value'],$row['rental_by_value']));
        }
        return $carRate;
```

In another page I receive it like this (OOP way):

```
$selectRate=$setting->selectRate();
```

And this outputs as below in `print_r($selectRate);`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => rental_distance [1] => 90 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => rental_distance [1] => 78 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => rental_distance [1] => 67 ) )
```

Now I need to get only the 90,78,67 from the above array, so I tried like below:

```
foreach($selectRate as $key=>$value)
{ 

    foreach($value as $v)
    {
        echo $v;
//outputs => rental_distance90rental_distance78rental_distance67
    }
}
```

2nd attempt:

```
foreach($selectRate['rental_by_value'] as $key=>$value)
    { 

        foreach($value as $v)
        {
            echo $v;
    //outputs => rental_distance90rental_distance78rental_distance67
        }
    }
```

This emits error saying invalid parameter supplied for foreach. How do I get only `['rental_by_value']` array values?

Comment: PHP >5.5 `array_column($your_array, 1)`

Comment: `echo $v[1]` in loop

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```
foreach($selectRate as $value)
{
   echo $value[1];
}
?>
```

You even dont need to mention custom index ($key)

Comment: thanx @Hanky웃Panky . Corrected

Answer (score 0):

And *just in case* you're using PHP >= 5.5 you could achieve what you want even without a loop, You could then use the built-in function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) in the following manner:

```
$values = array_column($selectRate, 1);
print_r($values);
```

You can [see it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xpM7W5)